# Strategies for localising keyboard shortcuts

Tags: localization, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently involved in a heavily localised WPF application and we've had a bug raised about keyboard shortcuts on menus in non-English languages. The bug referred to modifer key names (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc.) not being translated, which is easy enough to fix.

However, this got me thinking about the shortcut keys themselves, which are often based on the first letter of the command, except where this isn't feasible due to clashes or convention. When the command names are localised this link between the commands and their respective shortcuts will usually be lost:

- Is this worth worrying about?
- How do existing major applications cope with this problem?
- Are there any other issues to consider in this case?

Although this question was inspired by a WPF app, I'm more interested in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stay away from symbol-keys (such as <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd><</kbd>), since they tend to move around on international keyboards. See [Wikipedia: Keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Swedish.2FFinnish)

If you plan on switching the letters around depending on localization, you should enable the user to choose if he/she wants the English variants instead. It is frustrating if I have to learn two sets of shortcuts depending on the language. (Same goes for cross-platform applications.)

Best would be fully customizable keyboard shortcuts, but that could be more for power-users. See [Media Player Classic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/) for an example.

Comment: Some excellent points here. I wouldn't be bothered about symbols moving around, but it would be a big problem if they weren't available at all on some layouts.

Comment: Would you please tell what exactly does this mean: ' fully customizable keyboard shortcuts'?

Comment: The user can change the keyboard shortcut for any action that can be triggered by pressing something on the keyboard. Or conversely, change the action for any assignable keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

While searching for more info I found an excellent [blog post](http://blog.i18n.ro/are-we-supposed-to-localize-keyboard-shortcuts/) on this exact topic.

To summarise:

> - If possible the shortcut is not
>     changed
> - If a key is not available on
>     a specific layout we should try to use
>     the same physical position
> - There
>     should be no link between application
>     language and keyboard layouts
> - It’s a
>     mistake to consider that application
>     language will match the keyboard
>     layout. I’ll give you just an example:
>     in Romania over 95% of the computers
>     are using US keyboard layout and the
>     other 5% are using one of the 4-5
>     different Romanian keyboard layouts.
> - Some people are using multiple
>     keyboard layouts - usually they are
>     power users and we can’t ignore them 
>     keyboard layouts can be switched
>     anytime
> - Characters are safe to be
>     used only if they are Latin

Comment: Would you please tell what does 'latin characters' exactly mean in your last point? Which character are latins? A to Z are latin?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has guidelines on this, worth checking out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545460.aspx#choosing

And from [Top Guidelines Violations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511331.aspx):

- Don't confuse access keys with shortcut keys. While both access keys and shortcut keys provide keyboard access to UI, they have different purposes and guidelines.
- Assign shortcut keys to the most commonly used commands. Infrequently used programs and features don't need shortcut keys because users can use access keys instead.
- Don't assign different meanings to well-known shortcut keys. Because they are memorized, inconsistent meanings for well-known shortcuts are frustrating and error prone. For the well-known shortcut keys used by Windows programs, see Windows Keyboard Shortcut Keys.
- Don't try to assign system-wide program shortcut keys. Your program's shortcut keys will have effect only when your program has input focus.

Comment: These links are now broken

Comment: Is this the new URL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/a-z-word-list-term-collections/term-collections/keys-keyboard-shortcuts